# Is SO an inappropriate venue for assembling a development team for a new project?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, off-topic

**Does anyone know of any websites where developers propose software projects and try to recruit other developers to join them?** It's a pretty a straightforward idea, but I don't think I've come across one like that (OSS hosting sites like Sourceforge, Codeplex, Google Code, etc. are similar; but they're more about discovering *existing* projects and contributing if you're interested).

It seems like SO would be a logical place to seek out other developers who might be interested in collaborating on a new project (presumably OSS, but not necessarily). But then, this feels somewhat outside the realm of what SO is really for. Besides, it might be considered bad form to use it in this way. **Is it?**

Comment: This question should be added to the official FAQ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes! (under some circumstances)

If your team is being assembled for an open source project, you can use this **[advert thread on Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53346/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2010)** to request help from developers. It's legal, free and explicitly set up by SO for the purpose.

As users surf SO they see these open source adverts interspersed with commercial adverts. Keep refreshing the StackOverflow page and you will see one or two... eventually.

Comment: Ha! Definitely good to know. Not sure I could compete with the likes of those groups up top... but thanks, this is exactly what I was wondering about.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know of any websites where developers propose software projects and try to recruit other developers to join them?

careers.stackoverflow.com, monster.com, craigslist.com, dice.com

Answer (score -7):

Rather than paying a bunch of people, just pay one to ask sufficiently well formed questions to fool the answer guys into thinking you genuinely attempted a solution. That's really one of the great things about SO. It's like a free Apple-care policy for software development.

Comment: wow. dude, you might want to start deleting questions like this that are obviously not taken well. better yet, stop, count to 3 (slowly) and then consider whether you really want to add to your FUD factor.