# Where did all of the downvotes go?

Tags: status-completed, down-votes, meta, bug

Yesterday I had about 700 downvotes on Meta. Today I have 5. Look at [my profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/52443/weblog) if you don't believe me. [Shoggy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9), too. It looks like every user's downvotes have been removed from the system.

Huh? That can't be right. Downvotes appear to be unchanged on SO itself.

What gives? I can still downvote and my new downvotes appear, but all of the old ones are gone. Did Waffles break something?

Comment: THIEVES! WHO DID STEAL MY PRECIOUS VOTES?

Comment: I've still got all of my cast downvotes, but I have noticed a loss of received downvotes. Which actually earned me a badge. I wonder if it's a consequence of users who have lost their downvotes.

Comment: Time to go on a downvoting spree!

Comment: Just got a badge because of this. Still showing the down-votes I've cast. Is it due to some accounts being deleted?

Comment: @Grace: So not every user was affected. Weird.

Comment: I have 54 downvotes, not sure how many I had before or even if mine has changed.

Comment: Looking through the user list, it looks like users who had about 100 or more downvotes no longer have downvotes, but users with fewer than 100 got to keep theirs.

Comment: I checked my *real* reputation. Has gone up. My downvotes are not in the system anymore.

Comment: Pesto and Pekka both have >100 downvotes. And my original theory that it was only 10k users was also busted by Pesto. This is unprecedented serious affair!

Comment: I used to have a few hundred, now I have 0 downvotes. Damn! I worked hard for those. My real rep is about the same as what's actually shown, so the votes are definitely still there, they're just not showing in the profile page.

Comment: @Grace: Whatever the case it seems that users with a lot of downvotes have had their downvotes removed. It's going to take me a lot of time to get back up to 700 but I'm starting right away!

Comment: -1 so you can get your downvotes back faster. You're welcome.

Comment: @badp good point. Downvoted as well. Might as well start somewhere!

Comment: Still have all 28 of mine, and I'm glad. I have names for each of them and I talk to them every day. They keep me company, they console me when I'm sad, they inspire me when nothing else can. I'm afraid to say, I suspect mob involvement here .. your votes may have been sold into a down-vote slavery ring.

Comment: Guh? I went down from 405 to 1 downvote! They even disappeared from my rep audit!

Comment: Maybe it only affected users with a special down/up ratio. Or it is a weird bug, arbitrarily messing up votes. **Jeff, fix this!**

Comment: And we can't check OData because it's been taken down! I smell a conspiracy!

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I thougt this was for downvotes received, not downvotes given. Retag reverted.

Comment: Did [Jeff](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) *always* have no downvotes?

Comment: Good news everyone: I'm up to 30 downvotes. I can't do any more voting today. I'll begin anew tomorrow!

Comment: @Andy He is cheating anyway. When he wants to downvote you, he is changing the database tables directly.

Comment: @devinb the [db explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/) is still up

Comment: @Andy [Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:-Y-xlYjNaUsJ:meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood+site:http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) shows that Jeff had 214 downvotes prior to this.

Comment: @George: really, I expected more than that.

Comment: I went from {some positive integer} to 0 downvotes!  Time to change my Meta name to Adam!

Comment: Wondered how I got those new badges with no gain in rep.

Comment: @badp As you'll see from my answer, I discovered that :D

Comment: [Community User](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1) got to keep their downvotes! I call shenanigans on that!

Comment: Two new `Populist` s... interesting....

Comment: Could this be anything to do with a bunch of questions being migrated to the meta.superuser and meta.serverfault sites?

Comment: Downvotes have gone from all posts that still remain, so migration out of here can't account for all of those downvotes being lost. @sim

Comment: @random I'll bet someone tweaked the serial downvoting script.

Comment: For the record, I still have my > 100 SO downvotes.

Comment: `[status-workaround-found]`: turned my monitor upside down. Now meta looks normal again.

Comment: @devinb: I believe that there is some kind of anti-mob-vote in place, but you can't delete all the downvotes of several users just because they agree! I mean, we are few and know each other here, it's inevitable to vote in agreement several times without even knowing it. (I might be completely wrong, but seeing the list of affected users, we tend to agree on most things)

Comment: @perbert - I lost all my downvotes as well and I think Welbog would agree that it's highly unlikely that he and I would be in agreement very often on our downvotes.  My vote is for inadvertent data loss due to a poorly planned update or feature.  What is sad is that this has been noted for a couple of hours, it's at the top of the highly voted questions on meta right now, and no one from the team has weighed in to explain what happened or even that they are looking into it.

Comment: @tvanfosson: "I think Welbog would agree that it's highly unlikely that he and I would be in agreement very often on our downvotes." I don't really pay attention to you so I can't agree to this. Do you usually have very bad opinions? If so, then I can agree with it.

Comment: @tvanfosson I think it's likely that they are aware (at least Gravell should be, he's in UK IIRC) and are most likely currently attempting to fix it. I agree, it'd be nice to have a "[status-looking-into-it]"

Comment: @Welbog - it's been awhile but I thought we had crossed paths before on a couple of occasions. Perhaps I was thinking of someone else.  But, then again, given your snarky comment, perhaps not.

Comment: @tva: 1) I'd recommend moving the discussion about this theory to my answer. 2) I'm not talking consciously. I don't discuss votes with others, and given that there are few users, it's likely that you've agreed on voting on the same topic with a definable group several times. 3) We agree that whatever this was wasn't tested against the data. π) Or was an intended, even if IMO bad, result.

Comment: There is no conspiracy but the people who can sort this out are either asleep or going to sleep. Hold tight a few hours

Comment: @Waffles, isn't it like midnight where you are? Shouldn't you be asleep already? Or at least drunk?

Comment: Someone needs to wake the crew in the US.  There should be some paging system that every user has access to.

Comment: This is pretty serious -- 100% of mine are gone, too. And I don't downvote willy-nilly. Now I look like a perky polly or something! (Also, 5 of the affected users apparently downvoted my answer to the infamous "official chat" post. That didn't result in my populist badge, but it did help.)

Comment: I've lost 100% of my downvotes too, and picked up a couple of "Nice *" badges to boot (my user activity says this happened 6h ago as of this writing).  According to my reputation report, I've also lost all downvotes cast on my posts, too.

Comment: Throwing in my support for [oh-noes] on meta.

Comment: They do not want to see, @Justin.

Comment: @Lad Ignorance is bliss...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**This was completely my fault - the downvotes have been restored.**

This was related to question migration and mapping unassociated accounts on the destination site - this is why MSO was affected.

Downvotes were incorrectly set to the wrong target user, which made our serial downvoting task delete them.  But since this `Vote.TargetUserId` is a "denormalized" field (it's the Post's owner), fixing them wasn't too difficult.

In the future, please don't downvote so much :)

Comment: Could we please get some details on why it seemed to have no pattern to it?  Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: **HOORAY!** My downvotes are back! I missed you, you naughty little downvotes. Yes I did. Oh, downvotes, what *fun* we'll have together!

Comment: @Justin - the users that were affected had downvoted enough times in a day to have all their downvotes invalidated by the serial downvoting task.

Comment: You'd have better luck next time, or longer delay between notice, if you wiped them out in far smaller chunks.

Comment: `+1` for taking the blame.  `-1` for breaking it in the first place. `:P`

Comment: @Justin I felt like a complete idiot when I saw the code that had done it...  it was missing a pair of `( )` around an `or` statement.  That's what I get for coding on just a few hours sleep!

Comment: @Justin, I'd personally add an extra +1 for fixing it. So he still comes out on top. But I'm out of votes today, I spent them all trying to reclaim my downvotes.

Comment: @devinb I wonder what happens to any double-downvotes spawned by this.

Comment: Let this be a lesson to us all: When writing code, it's a good idea to be awake and alert. :) +1 Jarrod for fixing it and telling us what happened. (Now my new username makes no sense, but that's OK. My *precious* -- I mean, my downvote record -- is back.)

Comment: @Grace, you could find that in the data explorer i bet...next month

Comment: @imi, you could do the profile copy thing if you really wanna change it back.

Comment: @Grace. I hope they got hit twice! I only downvoted on the 20 items I disagree with most. Screw those guys!

Comment: I take it TDD is not being used by you guys?

Comment: @jin: Nah. I was tired of the Hunter Thompson reference anyway. Been looking for an excuse for a while. I'll just try to remember toward the end of August that I'm eligible for a new one then ...

Comment: @Jarrod, Sounds like you could use some: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRuNxHqwazs  (Possibly NSFW (contains the word f*ck in the video))

Comment: @Justin **RAWBERRY!**

Comment: Made with lightening, **REAL LIGHTENING!**

Comment: That's not how lightning is spelled.

Comment: @web, oops.  Spelling correctly is far too much work...

Comment: @Neil, isn't that exactly what TDD is?  You know, hammer away with random changes until the unit tests pass, then deploy it absentmindedly without any further QA?

Comment: Fun thing now is that totals of votes seem to be still wrong: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41959/41985#41985 shows -3, and -8 when clicked on.

Comment: @Gnoupi, could that be because of flags.  They don't show in the title, but they do when you split the votes.

Comment: @Justin: I don't think so - there are a *lot* of questions with bizarre voting breakouts now, and only 5 active flags.

Comment: @Aarobot Don't know - I never use the stuff (TDD) myself. But I do unit testing, which if the SO guys did might have spared them this embarrassment.

Comment: @Grace, I didn't downvote anything before this was fixed for exactly that reason.

Answer (score 6):

I firmly believe that this is a travesty. As someone with little to offer but my time and extensive vocabulary, my votes are the main way I can contribute.

***Both*** my votes, up and down, are indications of *actual* beliefs and opinions about posts. Wiping out nearly *half* of my contributions is completely unacceptable.

The following users had *at least* this many contributions obliterated. 
As of the last datadump, there were nearly 26000 downvotes. I have verified (hey, it's friday) that at least 14000 of them are gone now.

Note, Jeff Atwood and Robert Cartaino both had their contributions removed. 
Also, me.

The following is a list of those who were hardest hit.

```
User            Down    Up      Pecent
-------------- ------- ------- ------
G. Chetwood     1743    724     70.65
random          945     4763    16.56
Juan Manuel     875     436     66.74
The Proposer    688     450     60.46
N. Butterworth  566     427     57
Shog9           532     2584    17.07
Gnome           503     1319    27.61
alex            501     2547    16.44
Troggy          449     1277    26.01
Lance Roberts   370     2984    11.03
Ladybug Killer  328     2723    10.75
devinb          317     568     35.82
ire_and_curses  316     1575    16.71
Chacha102       314     544     36.6
Dr. Gonzo       307     2122    12.64
sth             307     446     40.77
Kop             293     872     25.15
Daniel Daranas  292     891     24.68
R. Cartaino     289     1214    19.23
perbert         289     1688    14.62
Ian Elliott     281     197     58
George Stocker  278     858     24.47  
Kev             276     551     33.37  
Stu Thompson    265     471     36.01  
Ether           251     1530    14.09  
dmckee          224     827     21.31  
fretje          223     1275    14.89  
Chester         208     665     23.83
Jon Sampson     208     975     17.58  
Jeff Atwood     200     2401    7.69
```

Comment: Nooooo... I was so proud of my downvotes...

Comment: @Juan, I know you were buddy, if you weren't so supportive of others, you probably could've taken the top spot!

Comment: @Juan It is a sad day when Downvoter no longer has downvotes.

Comment: I blame Sam and a failed query...

Comment: From the looks of this, need to get that ratio up and continue with the just downvoting.

Comment: @random I'll have to try and remember everything I've ever disagreed with and revisit them. I think I'll start with all the "Ignore a user" proposals, and move on to "contact someone directly"

Comment: As a result of this travesty, Dr. Gonzo has just become I miss my downvotes.

Comment: ::sniff:: ::sniff: I want to thank my wife and my parents and my manager and all the little people. ::sob::

Comment: This is very sad, even Robert and Jeff got hit.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the people affected, I can distinctly see two groups of Meta regulars with very defined ideas on several topics (even if those "groups" actually change between topics), which gives me the gut feeling that some kind of anti-mob-vote-script has been deployed, and has hit all of the Meta regulars merely because we are few and tend to fall in one of two or three groups per topic (inclusionists/deletionists, pro-cursing/anti-cursing/meh-cursing, pepsi/coca-cola, vim/emacs, C#/Java, etc.).

If this is true, I not only think that the implementation really sucks, it didn't take into account that people in small communities (Meta/obscure tags) *will* trigger this.

This is discouraging to say the least.

If there is another reason, the only I can think about is that Jeff wanted to give Meta a clean state of downvotes for whatever reason, or that he is preparing us to take away the downvoting mechanism form Meta, which would be a far worse mistake than whatever happened here.

---

Seems like we got our downvotes back.

Mmm...

[image: It's a conspiracy!]

Comment: Extreme form of this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42601/should-we-have-a-policy-about-too-much-downvoting

Comment: @ran: You mean `status-declined` was a misnomer?

Comment: Wiping out the downvotes on the anti-downvote policy would allow for it to be reconsidered as now the score is in the positive. @lad

Comment: @ran: that's a throw-22!

Comment: I don't necessarily believe that this is a mob-vote script. I'd downvote you, but I'm all tapped out.

Answer (score 6):

Hopefully this is just a dev bug that will be corrected and not some sly way to slip [an anti-downvote policy beneath our chins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42601/should-we-have-a-policy-about-too-much-downvoting).

Not like people are really [afraid of downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21080/why-are-people-afraid-of-downvotes) are they?

If they are, they need to stop with the bad ideas and suggestions and grow a spine to smoke in their hydroponic labs.

Without downvoting as a way to temper good from bad, it's too much hippie free love that distorts the real reflection of the community's opinion.

Comment: How appropriate that the anti-downvote post had a score of -20 yesterday and, oh look, today it has a positive score again!

Comment: Hey, you're ignoring all the positive things that hippies provide. Like... veganism, and... organic vegetables... and ummm... <strike>vans</strike> *love*.

Comment: @devinb: Don't forget firewalking and raw food diets.  And dirt.  Lots and lots of dirt.

Answer (score 5):

Currently (according to the API) these are the users that have downvoted the most. (Top 30)  Weblog hasn't even made it onto the list yet.

**Edit:**  Ran it again, check out the new list of top downvoters

```
Rich B: 1743
random: 1047
Juan Manuel: 901
Weblog: 791
Neil Butterworth: 609
Shog9: 589
Gnome: 518
alex: 509
Troggy: 451
devinb: 439
Lance Roberts: 391
Ladybug Killer: 357
Kop: 328
Chacha102: 324
ire_and_curses: 324
sth: 318
Robert Cartaino: 316
I miss my downvotes: 316
perbert: 309
Daniel Daranas: 300
George Stocker: 291
Kev: 284
Ian Elliott: 281
Stu Thompson: 267
Ether: 264
dmckee: 237
fretje: 225
Jeff Atwood: 219
Chester: 210
Jonathan Sampson: 208
John Rasch: 195
```

Old list:

```
Isaac Waller: 188
Pekka: 151
waiwai933: 141
Hilarious Comedy Pesto: 139
beska: 136
balpha: 126
quack quixote: 111
Earlz: 103
innaM: 100
TheTXI: 96
raven: 96
Dexter: 95
Brandon: 94
Nifle: 94
squillman: 93
Arjan: 93
Georg: 86
Grace Note: 82
AnonJr: 80
marcgg: 69
Pavel Shved: 68
waffles: 67
Mehrdad: 63
Software Monkey: 63
Farseeker: 62
Sinan ÃœnÃ¼r: 62
Robert Harvey: 59
gnovice: 58
Macha: 58
Michael Petrotta: 58
```

Code: (Uses [StackWrap4J](https://stackapps.com/questions/818/stackwrap4j-java-wrapper))

```
  UserQuery query = new UserQuery();
  query.setPageSize(100);
  UsersList users = new UsersList(new Meta(), query);
  Collections.sort(users, new Comparator<User>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
          return -1 * (o1.getDownVotes() - o2.getDownVotes());
      }
  });
  for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
      User u = users.get(i);
      System.out.println(u.getDisplayName() + ": " + u.getDownVotes());
  }
```

Comment: Judging from devin's report and yours, it looks like the cut-off point was 200 downvotes.

Comment: Bwahahah! The shoe is on the other foot now, meta, it is I who have downvoted you!

Comment: @Grace, actually, it appeared to be nearly all users. I just cut off my own at 200. There were many users with fewer than 100 downvotes who still lost them all. Marc Gravell for one.

Comment: Those numbers are so horribly low.

Comment: @random Yeah, it is a bizarre occurrence.

Comment: @devin: Weird. I've been trolling the first page of users, and mostly it looks right -- until I get to [balpha](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha). He apparently *kept* his, and while they're < 200, they do comprise 15.3% of his total votes.

Comment: @I miss: Yeah, it certainly wasn't a "number of downvotes" cutoff, it wasn't a percentage cutoff, it wasn't a timeframe cutoff, it wasn't a user/rep cutoff.

Comment: @devinb: Combination, perhaps?

Comment: @Imiss We think it might be a 'anti-mob-vote' script gone wrong.  See @perbert's answer.

Comment: @jin: I'd think the same thing, but ... There should be a discernible pattern then, no?

Comment: Best way to cover up something like this is to throw some users across the board to defray the load actually targeted. Conspiracy theory 101. @imi

Comment: @imi, I dunno.  The data is so complex.  We just may not be able to see the pattern.

Comment: I still have all 8 of my downvotes.

Comment: @jin: That does make sense. Especially if the script ran a combination, like total # of votes vs downvotes vs percentage or something crazy ...

Comment: Yeah, that would be too much calculations to just *see* a pattern. (@imi)

Comment: Woot! Top spot! Suck on that upvoters!

Comment: Awesome! I've moved up since the last datadump! @Random I'm gunning for your spot!

Comment: @Lad, thanks for fixing that.  I'm not sure why he got left out.

Comment: @devin, if you want to see real time progress, the API is 100% real-time!

Comment: @Justin: Probably his suspension? Dang, thought I was in the top 15, actually #18 ...

Comment: @Justin, I waste enough of my time here without having it be real time. That would be disasterous.

Answer (score 3):

`revision: 2010.7.30.2`. It's probably a bug in the **.2** revision, which was apparently deployed a few hours ago.

Thankfully it was deployed on meta only (SO is on `2010.7.30.1`), and I really hope it's reversible and that our precious downvotes aren't lost forever. =(

EDIT: now it changed to `revision: 2010.7.30.3`

Comment: And in the meantime, be sure to spam moderators to have your reputation recalculated :]

Comment: ahah yes, I just gained 400 rep, hurray =)

Comment: **JEFF, FIX THIS!**

Comment: @Kop - I'll recalc you once fixed, don't jump too high :P

Comment: They've gone to the big absolute value in the sky ....

Comment: I'm just waiting for Jeff to edit the tags to `[status-bydesign]` ;)

Comment: @Tim, I'm offended that your absolute value joke. Sinners go to hell!

Comment: @dev: so if downvotes are sins, and we've got all our downvotes deleted, we've just been excommunicated or took sacrament?

Comment: @devinb - it is conceivable that I spend most of my time standing on my head, hence my orientation is reversed.

Comment: Oddly, my visible reputation is still 700 *above* my actual reputation (15899 visible vs. 15122 actual) -- that's quite a huge discrepancy, considering we had a global rep recalc only a few months ago.

Comment: @Ether, the SuperUser and ServerFault questions got migrated. That's a huge chunk of rep that floated away.

Comment: @Kop: Thanks for the edit; hadn't noticed that the build number changed. **Note:** Meta is at 2010.7.30.3; SO itself is now at 2010.7.30.2. I did a check of a certain [binned user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5640/geoffrey-chetwood) and all his downvotes seem to be intact, so I **am** thinking this was a specific, targeted Meta-only, non-build-related sweep and change. But why scrub their own staff/mods in it? And why the deafening silence -- if they're dropping builds, they've seen this. And is anyone else afraid to downvote anymore -- I feel like why bother if they'll just be wiped out.

Comment: @devinb: that would seem logical, except I have 0 questions and answers on meta.SF/SU. curious...

Comment: @Ether: Could be they just weren't associated properly. I have at least one 8-vote answer on Meta.SF that isn't shown on my account.

Comment: @mmyers: yep, that's it -- google found lots of such answers. Will flag to get fixed; thanks. :)

Comment: 8565 -> 7919, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I lost all my downvotes to this, and even Jeff Atwood lost [214 downvotes](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:-Y-xlYjNaUsJ:meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood+site:https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us).

Comment: Pre recalc (where downvotes existed): 13,863; Post: 14,228